# Why is the 98th element in my Stack implementation such a bizarre value?

Tags: c++, stack

I have the following stack data structure implementation in C++:

```
// file: Stack.h
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <exception>
class CStack
{
private:
    int counter;
    int *data;
    int currentmaxsize;
    void adjust();
public:
    void push(int value);
    int pop();
    int peek();
    int getsize();
    CStack();
    ~CStack();
};


// file: Stack.cpp
#include "Stack.h"

void CStack::adjust()
{
    int *temp = new int[currentmaxsize];
    for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++)
    {
        temp[i] = data[i];
    }
    delete data;
    data = new int[currentmaxsize * 2];
    for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++)
    {
        data[i] = temp[i];
    }
    delete temp;
    currentmaxsize *= 2;
}

int CStack::getsize()
{
    return counter;
}

void CStack::push(int value)
{
    if (counter+1 == currentmaxsize)
    {
        adjust();

    }
    counter++;

    data[counter] = value;
}

int CStack::peek()
{
    return data[counter];
}

int CStack::pop()
{
    if (counter > 0)
    {
        int ret = data[counter];
        counter--;
        return ret;
    }
    else if (counter == 0)
    {
        throw std::exception("cannot pop empty stack");
    }
    return 0xFFFFFFFF;

}

CStack::CStack()
{
    data = new int[100];
    currentmaxsize = 100;
    counter = 0;
}


CStack::~CStack()
{
    delete data;
}
```

This is a fairly standard stack implementation. The only thing that is different from the kind of stack you would see in most textbooks is the adjust() function, which reallocates the stack with a bigger size if the original boundary is reached.

I wrote the following driver for the data structure as well:

```
// file: driver.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "Stack.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    CStack stack;
    for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++)
    {
        stack.push(i);
        std::cout << "Pushed: " << i << std::endl;

        //std::cout << "New stack size: " << stack.getsize() << std::endl;
    }
    int len = stack.getsize();
    std::cout << "len = " << len << std::endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        std::cout << "Popped: " << stack.pop() << std::endl;
        //std::cout << "New stack size: " << stack.getsize() << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This works *almost* as I would expect it to, except this one value in the program output:

```
Popped: 100
Popped: 99
Popped: 7798895
Popped: 97
Popped: 96
```

It is always the value of the 98th element in the stack that has a bizarre value like this, and I don't know why it is - the adjust() function is being called when the stack hits 100 values, not 99, so I don't imagine it's a problem with the adjust function.

Comment: Wrong form of `delete`.  It should be `delete []`, not `delete`.  Also, why two allocations in `adjust`?  All you need is one.

Comment: In addition, when you expand data, there is no need to copy it to temp, then copy the whole array back to data.  Instead, create temp to be twice as big as data as per the bottom part, then copy everything from data and replace data with temp once only.

Comment: And BTW, that strange value is only by chance.  It is a clear indication you've got an off-by-one (or two) issue with your indices somewhere.

Comment: `counter++;` followed by `data[counter] = value;` is wrong (You should ensure `counter` is always past the end of stack elements)

Comment: As to what @DieterLücking stated -- if you would have made `currentmaxsize` equal to 1, the mistake he mentioned would have been obvious.  Always tests the extremes -- You didn't know what would happen until you added 100 items to your stack, why wait?  See what happens when you add just 1 item with a mimimal capacity setting.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `push` and `peek` and probably other functions use `counter` as the index of the last element.  But other parts of your code use `counter` as the number of elements so `counter-1` would be the index of last.  So data is lost during `adjust`

Select one design:  The valid indexes are 0 through `counter-1` inclusive **or** 0 though `counter` **or** 1 through `counter` (wasting position 0).

I only like the first of those choices but any one of them can work (your existing code is closest to being the third).  Having different parts play by different rules doesn't work.

Comment: This solved it; indexing the stack off `counter-1` for the `push`/`pop`/`peek` operations works perfectly.

Answer (score -1):

I see at least one bug.  You are using `delete` after doing a `new[]`.

`new` should be matched with `delete` and `new[]` should be matched with `delete[]`. Otherwise it's undefined behavior.

Also, you are doing unnecessary copying in your `adjust` function.

Comment: Correction: You should not use `delete` or `delete[]` at all, and very rarely `new` and never `new[]`. Always use library classes like a vector.

Comment: @Puppy I was answering the question that was asked, not recoding it.  If you want to answer the question differently, feel free.

Comment: @Puppy I get the reasoning behind this, but, techcically, on MSVC at least, the `new` and `delete` operators are implemented in the CRT as library functions as well.

Comment: @GovindParmar I assume you are doing the above as a learning exercise.  I would never code a stack for real use since the `C++ standard library` already has a `std::stack` container adapter.

Comment: @AnonMail Yep - I am doing this as an exercise for  learning C++